# Sizing issue of table-cell elements, why?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to arrange an input-group. I'm using bootstrap, but the issue is (fortunately) reproducible in pure HTML/CSS as well.

I have a 100% width `display: table` container, and I'm trying to put a `16.666%` width `span`, and a `83.3333%` width `input` into it. But due to the strangest magic I'm ever seen, they don't fill the entire space. When inspecting the elements, I can see that the `span` width is calculated correctly, but the `input` width is far less than it should be, hence it doesn't fill the space that it should.

However, if I put two `input` elements (so an `input` instead of the `span`, it works as expected.

Please check out this [DEMO fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4q40j22/)

I've reproduced the issue in Chrome latest, and IE11 too, so I guess it's not a specific browser bug.

I'd like to know what's happening, and how to achieve my goal if not like this.

Comment: Try specifying `style="width:100%"` for the elements within the cells.

Comment: The first table-cell element  takes `16.66%` of the total width. While the second `table-cell` takes `83.33%` of the remaining width (ie `83.33% * (100% - 16.33%)`). So in order for the input to take the full width set the `width : 100%`

Comment: I want to two element together to take the full width, hence the 16.66 and 83.33 widths, they add together to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use input as table-cell. Use something else instead and then set input to width 100% so it will fill the container.

Also added table-row:

```
<div class="w6">
  <div style="display: table; background-color: brown;">
    <div style="display: table-row" class="w12">
      <span class="w2" style="display: table-cell; background-color: blue;"></span>
      <!--<input type="text" class="w2"/>-->
      <span class="w10">
        <input type="text" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4q40j22/1/

Comment: Unfortunately Bootstrap uses `table-cell` on inputs within `input-group`, so it might solve the example but is not suitable for my real scenario. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Actually it seems like I can solve it with an added wrapping `span`, because Bootstrap CSS doesn't use the children selector but only the descendant, so it styles inputs within the `span` too. I'll experiment with it, but thank again for the tip. Do you probably know the reason why it's not working with `input` directly? And why it does with two `input`s?

Comment: I don't know the reason and I never used input as it is in your example. Generally, inputs are specific in html and my experience say that I should avoid to style them in different way. Inputs are just inline-block(s) and with width 100% it works fine. If you create container for it, you can also change it's maximal width.

Comment: Ok, I feel the same about inputs being "specific". Thanks again, I will work Bootstrap around and use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Set the css class for input as `w12` so that the width is set to 100% of the remaining width

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.w1 {
  width: 8.33333333% !important;
}
.w2 {
  width: 16.66666667% !important;
}
.w3 {
  width: 25% !important;
}
.w4 {
  width: 33.33333333% !important;
}
.w5 {
  width: 41.66666667% !important;
}
.w6 {
  width: 50% !important;
}
.w7 {
  width: 58.33333333% !important;
}
.w8 {
  width: 66.66666667% !important;
}
.w9 {
  width: 75% !important;
}
.w10 {
  width: 83.33333333% !important;
}
.w11 {
  width: 91.66666667% !important;
}
.w12 {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="w6">
  <div class="w12" style="display: table; background-color: brown;">
    <span class="w2" style="display: table-cell; background-color: blue;"></span>
    <!--<input type="text" class="w2"/>-->
    <input type="text" class="w12"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I see that it works if I set it to 100%, but I wonder why. According to my best knowledge, 16.66 + 83.33 should be 100, and 16.66 + 100 should be 116.66